# How to Select data from multiple tables with several conditions?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

> There are tables FACULTIES (F_NUMB, F_NAME, F_TELEF) and STUDENTS (S_NUM, SURNAME, SPECIALITY, GROUP, FACULTY_NUMB). 
>   Please write SQL query to achieve faculties names in which the count of students are greater than in faculty “Computer science”.

This is what I'm doing:

```
select faculties.f_name, count(STUDENTS.S_NUM) from STUDENTS, FACULTIES
where students.fac_num=FACULTIES.F_NUMB group by faculties.f_name
having count(STUDENTS.S_NUM) > (select STUDENTS.S_NUM from STUDENTS, FACULTIES
where faculties.f_name='Computer Science' and students.fac_num=faculties.f_numb);
```

But still it is not working. Please help me..

Comment: the subquery in the having needs to be a count or your're comparing a number to the string studnets.s_num.

Comment: i'm just counting the number of students in order to compare it with the number of students in another faculty.

Comment: Yes, but you're counting in the main query, but not in the sub-query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT f.f_name
FROM faculties f
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) -- Here we get the student count for the faculty
  FROM students s 
  WHERE f.f_numb = s.faculty_numb) > 
  (SELECT COUNT(1)  -- Here we get the CS faculty student count
  FROM students s JOIN faculties f ON (f.f_numb = s.faculty_numb) 
  WHERE  f.f_name = 'Computer science');
```

For each row you check how many students the faculty has and compare it against the number of students the "Computer science" faculty has.

Answer (score 0):

```
with
  VW_FACULTIES as 
  ( SELECT f.*,
           ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
             FROM STUDENTS s 
             WHERE s.fac_num = f.f_numb) AS StudentCount
    FROM FACULTIES f)

SELECT
  *
FROM
  VW_FACULTIES f
WHERE
  f.StudentCount > ( SELECT StudentCount 
                     FROM VW_FACULTIES 
                     WHERE f_name='Computer Science')
```